# OpenCV error: [mpeg4 @ 0x7ffe33cb3e60] too many thread_release_buffer calls

Tags: matlab, opencv, ffmpeg

I installed OpenCV in Ubuntu according to the official guide, then I'm trying to decode a file, then error occurs:

```
[mpeg4 @ 0x7ffe33cb3e60] too many thread_release_buffer calls!
[mpeg4 @ 0x7ffe33cb3e60] too many thread_release_buffer calls!
[mpeg4 @ 0x7ffe33cb3e60] too many thread_release_buffer calls!
[mpeg4 @ 0x7ffe33cb3e60] too many thread_release_buffer calls!
[mpeg4 @ 0x7ffe33cb3e60] too many thread_release_buffer calls!
[mpeg4 @ 0x7ffe33cb3e60] too many thread_release_buffer calls!
[mpeg4 @ 0x7ffe33cb3e60] too many thread_release_buffer calls!
[mpeg4 @ 0x7ffe33cb3e60] too many thread_release_buffer calls!
[mpeg4 @ 0x7ffe33cb3e60] too many thread_release_buffer calls!
[mpeg4 @ 0x7ffe33cb3e60] too many thread_release_buffer calls!
[mpeg4 @ 0x7ffe33cb3e60] too many thread_release_buffer calls!
[mpeg4 @ 0x7ffe33cb3e60] too many thread_release_buffer calls!
[mpeg4 @ 0x7ffe33cb3e60] too many thread_release_buffer calls!
[mpeg4 @ 0x7ffe33cb3e60] too many thread_release_buffer calls!
[mpeg4 @ 0x7ffe33cb3e60] too many thread_release_buffer calls!
[mpeg4 @ 0x7ffe33cb3e60] too many thread_release_buffer calls!
[mpeg4 @ 0x7ffe33cb3e60] too many thread_release_buffer calls!
[mpeg4 @ 0x7ffe33cb3e60] too many thread_release_buffer calls!
```

the video is about 150 frames, the error log may exceed 1000, can someone help me here? thanks.

Comment: These errors do not stop the running, so we can ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the FFmpeg libraries. Older versions had a buffer limit which seems to be removed in the current git version.

It used to be:

```
#define MAX_BUFFERS (32+1)

...

if (p->num_released_buffers >= MAX_BUFFERS) {
         av_log(p->avctx, AV_LOG_ERROR, "too many thread_release_buffer calls!\n");
         return;
}
```

See the old [libavcodec/pthread.c](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.10/pthread_8c-source.html) versus the [new version](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/pthread.c) of the same file.